# Forces & Tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I need some assistance, I believe I might have made an incorrect assumption and don't understand why it was incorrect. I hope nobody has no qualms about visiting a PDF link, I have no screen capture applications on this computer, so I need to download which will take a few minutes. The question I will referring to in this post is on the 7th page of the PDF. Q7, June 2005.

[image: The question states the following:]

Since we are told that vehicles are connected via a **light** towbar, we can then assume the mass is negligible correct? Also, we can further assume that the acceleration of both vehicles are the same, since towbar's don't stretch correct?

With all the above considerations made, I proceeded to draw a force diagram for the lorry, since working out the acceleration on that object looked easier. The forces that acted on the lorry was $1500 N$ due to the engine and $-600N$ due to kinetic friction. Those are the only forces affecting the vehicle in the horizontal direction, thefore $$ a = \frac{F}{m}= \frac{1500N - 600N}{1600kg} = 0.5625ms^{-2} $$

However, apparently this is incorrect.

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking without clicking on the link you provided. To make questions more accessible and guard against [link rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot), please include all relevant information, such as the explanation of notation or specific terminology used, in your question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Yes, sorry. I will uploading a image shortly, it's just that my  pc is taking a while to install gyazo screen capture

Comment: Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but *type it out instead* so it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/143136) instead.

Comment: @ACuriousMind All done, edited and picture uploaded. Do you mind helping me out? I looked at your profile and you seem very experienced in physics and maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten the force on the lorry provided by the towbar. Until you know what this is, you cannot include it in your calculation.

You have already deduced that the lorry and car have the same acceleration. Ignore internal forces (ie that in the towbar) by considering them as a single object. Their common acceleration = total external force / total mass.

The "force from the engine" is the force with which the lorry's wheels push backwards on the road. The friction force from the road ("traction") is equal and opposite (Newton's 3rd Law) and pushes forward on the lorry's driving wheels. Traction is not an internal force.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I knew naught of that last sentence. I would have included it as a internal, if you hadn't told me. Suppose the two vehicles were connected by instead a light string or a light cord, would there be notable changes in the way you could approach this question

Comment: A string in tension is the same as a bar in tension. If the lorry decelerates, the string *might* become slack, whereas the bar can exert a compressive force between the car and lorry.

Comment: If the lorry were to decelerate, under what conditions would the string **not** slack? I would have thought in all cases of the lorry decelerating the string would become slack.

Comment: If the car were not towed, it would decelerate due to friction at 300N/900kg = 1/3 m/s^2. If the lorry decelerates faster than this, a towrope would become slack.